# Camera shortcut keys for Mac keyboard

Tags: shortcut, osx

What are the short cut keys to change between the views like top view, front view and things like that in a mac keyboard. as the kets 1, 2 and 3 are now being used for switching between the edge, vertex and face mode. I am a beginner, please do let me know.

Thank you for you help team..:)

Using 2.8, and an iMac.

Comment: Are you talking about 2.79 or 2.8? Are you using a Macbook or a normal Mac?

Comment: 2.8, and an iMac...:)

Comment: Ok, I mainly work on a Macbook and on 2.79 so I may be not the best to tell. Anyway, you could change the shortcuts, for the views I guess it's in the Preferences > Input > 3D View > 3D View (Global) > View Numpad, for the vertex/edge/face select modes: Input > 3D view > Mesh > Call Menu.

Comment: Thank you moonboots. I've tried that... But for now i guess i will stick with clicking on them from the gizmo..:)

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Edit* -> *Preferences*. In the preferences window click the *Input* tab. On the top click *Keyboard*, then check the *Emulate Numpad* box. Pressing numbers <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> will switch between *front view* and *side view*.

[image: edit menu, preferences at bottom]

[image: preferences window with the input tab and emulate numpad checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having trouble to this problem and start finding ways to fix it on internet or by myself here what I found hope this help[image]